# Can we apply index to match a certain value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

i have a collection named users as shown below .

```
     db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("512efc206074b0e4bbdce792"),
        "login_id" : "dutchuser",
        "isBroker" : false

}
```

I want to apply index for this users collection with the login_id and isBroker field also .

```
db.users.ensureIndex( { "login_id": 1, "isBroker": 1 }, { unique: false } )
```

My concern is that most of the **isBroker** field has got a value of **false** .
So is there any possibility that i can apply index in that way ??

Comment: do you want to avoid creating a big index or are concerned about query performance? (did you add a look at : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-compound). If you are concerned about query perf your index would perform better with isBroker first.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't quite get what your asking

Comment: @nomoa , i have gone through that before posting this . I need both the query performance as well as avoid creating big index . so cant i achieve both of them with the above index i posted .

Comment: @Sammaye , most of the documents in the collection have got the isBroker field value as false , so i want to create a index with the false value so that i can better performance results .

Comment: If most of your docs are not brokers, and you want to query something such as "who are my broker users"?, you can omit / unset all isBroker : false fields, and create a [Sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-sparse) such as `db.coll.ensureIndex( { "login_id": 1, "broker" : 1 }, { sparse: true } )` for the rest

Comment: @orid thanks you mean to say that i need to remove the isBroker attribute field/ attribute from all my documents in the collection and then use the sparse index ??

Comment: No, I meant removing only where isBroker is false. But since you are interested in your non broker users, which are the majority, and not in the broker users, I doubt if you benefit from it

Comment: @orid thanks i got what you meant .

Comment: Do you have evidence that your index will be too large and not perform well if you just index the value as you've suggested?

Comment: I do not believe a sparse index would perform

Comment: @WiredPrairie , no i dont have any such evidence . i just want to make things better in my environment .

Comment: Seems like a premature "optimization" that may complicate your schema/configuration for little to zero gain. With the compound index, you won't be able to answer questions efficiently like, "find me all non-brokers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot conditionally apply a filter to an index in MongoDB. While you could potentially restructure your data or introduce additional, potentially duplicate fields in your schema, I'm not convinced it's a reasonable "optimization."

Use `db.stats()` to actually measure the size of the database and `db.{collectionname}.totalIndexSize()` to see what the impact of having the index you proposed really is.

By using this index:

```
db.users.ensureIndex( { "login_id": 1, "isBroker": 1 }, { unique: false } )
```

You can only use queries that involve `login_id` and `isBroker` or just `login_id`. Depending on the types of queries that you run, you may also run into [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3310) currently open issue that might make a simple grouping/sorting on `isBroker` inefficient (or if at some point it becomes `broker_type` for example).